# Time to Put Together an Offer Letter - Major U.S. Accounting Firm

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer, human-resources

Last month, I went through the interview process with a major NYC-based accounting firm.  I attended four interviews, progressively meeting higher and higher-ranking executives within the department.  About a week following my interview with the top exec., I received a call from him saying that I was their top candidate, and that they'd put together an offer letter.

HR contacted me that same day to request full compensation history detail.  I was a bit reluctant to relay this (as I know I am not by law required to do so), and I believe I have been pretty seriously underpaid compared to market standards and holding a graduated degree.  I was likely underpaid due to the down market from 2008 onward, and given that I have required work authorization sponsorship until this year - now I am a green card holder.

Nonetheless, I relayed comp. history to HR via a very cordial email sent that same day.  I did not receive a response email to this, but I assumed that the process was moving forward at that point.

Now it has been a full two weeks since I've had any news.  I sent a follow-up email two days ago asking if they should need any additional info. from me at the moment and to enjoy the long weekend.

Still nothing.  Of course, I've continued my search, but I am wondering if a major, well-established, large U.S. accounting firm is normally taking more than two weeks *just to put together an initial job offer letter/package*....

Any thoughts from anyone in major financial firm HRs?  Does it take more than two weeks to put together the initial offer?  If there was an issue -- ie. a reference not returning their call, a flag of some sort in the process, a change in interest or a new top candidate....-- then wouldn't HR call to let me know?

Comment: I've proposed a duplicate because I believe that's the best answer to your question. Someone else may be able to give you more insight into how things work at a large accounting firm, but for the most part, the process is company-specific, and the larger the company, the slower the process.

Answer (score 5):

I am not in the field of finance, but I know for a fact that, as far as the big corporations go, they are s-l-o-o-o-w-w-w when it comes to hiring. Probaly your package will need signatures from your direct supervisor (gonna-be) to the higher ups, sometimes to VP of the division. If one or two of these guys/gals are on vacation schedules (consider it is spring break time) the papers will not be ready at the pace you would expect.

Other than that, it depends how you worded your compensation expectations. Without knowing the tone of your email and the company hiring practices and initial offers, it is hard to tell. But all that we know, your expectations might have sounded too much for them and they might have moved to the next candidate. And in these situations, nobody in the company wants to be the bad news bear, giving you this unpleasant news. If you are not hired, sometimes they don't even contact you. It is very unprofessional and chicken-like on their part, but it happens.

Keep looking for a new position and before you find anything, they turn up with the offer letter, good for you. Otherwise, good luck to them, as you might be at your new workplace.

Comment: Thanks Mel - and thanks to you, too, mcknz!  I'll continue looking.  It's been a really tough search this past year -- everyone (in media, at least) says what a more flexible, promising job market and economy we have now....I have to say that this is FAR from my experience, despite being fairly consistently employed over the years.  Thanks again, and I'll keep everyone posted.